# Is it possible to pass an argument to a celery task in django settings?

Tags: django, celery

I have the following entry in my settings.py file:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'exec-task-every-hour': {
    'task': 'app1.tasks.task1',
    'schedule': crontab(hour='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23', minute='0')
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly.

Is it possible to add an argument, and pass it through this settings entry, to the task being called (task1)?

Comment: Note that if you want to run the task every hour, you can use `hour='*'` (or just leave out the `hour` argument entirely) rather than listing all hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - add an `'args'` list (or a `'kwargs'` dictionary to pass keyword arguments) alongside `'task'` and `'schedule'`.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'exec-task-every-hour': {
        'task': 'app1.tasks.task1',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23', minute='0'),
        'args': (123, ),
    }
}
```

See also: [celerybeat docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v2.3.3/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries)